# Ruby on rails can't create with params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-submit

I have a from created in Ruby on rails. The code the form looks like this:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@action) do |f|%>
    <%= render 'shared/error_messages' %>

    <%=f.label :action_name, "Action name"%>
    <%=f.text_field :action_name%></br>

    <%=f.input :startDate,:as => :datetime_picker, :label =>"Start date"%>
    <%=f.input :endDate,:as => :datetime_picker, :label =>"End date"%>

    <%=f.label :contentURL, "Content url"%>
    <%=f.text_field :contentURL%></br>
<%= f.button :submit, class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>

    <%end%>
```

But when I click the submit button I get this error:

```
undefined method `permit' for "create":String

def action_params
    params.require(:action).permit(:action_name, :startDate,:endDate,:contentURL)
```

All other forms a working ok, I guess it is something really obvious, just can't see it :(
I really appreciate any help, solving this problem.

Thanks!!

EDIT:

Controller code:

```
def create
action = Action.new(action_params)
if @action.save
    flash[:success] = "New Action saved"
    redirect_to "/"
  else
    render 'new'
  end


 end

 private

 def action_params
     params.require(:action).permit(:action_name, :startDate,:endDate,:contentURL)
 end
```

Comment: this is the error of strong parameter, you will declare here params which you want to access or permit.... can you put your controller code here

Comment: Added controller code

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 4, you must use Strong Parameters in your controllers. [Here](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2012/3/21/strong-parameters/)'s some explanation from the official blog. And some example:

```
class PeopleController < ActionController::Base
  # This will raise an ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributes exception because it's using mass assignment
  # without an explicit permit step.
  def create
    Person.create(params[:person])
  end

  # This will pass with flying colors as long as there's a person key in the parameters, otherwise
  # it'll raise a ActionController::MissingParameter exception, which will get caught by 
  # ActionController::Base and turned into that 400 Bad Request reply.
  def update
    redirect_to current_account.people.find(params[:id]).tap do |person|
      person.update_attributes!(person_params)
    end
  end

  private
    # Using a private method to encapsulate the permissible parameters is just a good pattern
    # since you'll be able to reuse the same permit list between create and update. Also, you
    # can specialize this method with per-user checking of permissible attributes.
    def person_params
      params.required(:person).permit(:name, :age)
    end
end
```

Notice how, in the last lines, under the `private` keyword, the `person_params` method is defined, which declares the permitted fields to be assigned by the `create` and update methods on top. And it's the `person_params` that is used for updating - the valid example - instead of the raw params array.